# Run SQL Query With Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-injection

I know to prevent SQL Injection you would use parameters like `@param1` and `@param2` -- but how would you achieve such when you need to pass the same parameters multiple times?

Now the params would be passed in from two text boxes on a winform.  But again my ? is how does C# handle passing params to 2 different locations in the sql string?

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
       Select
       RTRIM(LTRIM(employeename)) As employeename
       ,psrti
       ,nes
       FROM helper1
)
Select 
[Employee Name] = RTRIM(LTRIM(cte.employeename))
,[days employed] = (Select COUNT([days]) 
                           FROM [empinfo] jb 
                           WHERE CAST([hiredate] As Date) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
                           AND RTRIM(LTRIM(jb.employeename)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(cte.employeename)))
,[terminated emps] = (Select Count(empID) from terminate where termination date between @startdate AND @enddate)
FROM hrfile  hr1
RIGHT JOIN CTE cte
ON hr1.employeename = cte.employeename
GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM(cte.employeename)),RTRIM(LTRIM(hr1.employeename)),cte.nes
ORDER BY RTRIM(LTRIM(cte.employeename)) ASC
```

I know with just the 1st set of params I would do

```
string sql = "";;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
  var param1 = new SqlParameter("param1", SqlDbType.DateTime);
  var param2 = new SqlParameter("param2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
  param1.Value = txtOne.Text;
  param2.Value = txtTwo.Text;
  command.Parameters.Add(param1);
  command.Parameters.Add(param2);
  var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: as long as your SQL string is formatted correctly it will handle reading your parameters any number of times. I would however convert to stored procedure, none the less.

Comment: @DaniDev - would a stored proc be faster than a direct sql statement?  In my test instances the direct sql statement has been faster.

Comment: 2 reasons:
1. Stored procedures are much easier to debug if you have a somewhat complex query as you have.
2. it's Safer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the same (set the parameter value only once) even when the parameters are used multiple times. C#/ADO.NET will take care of replacing the parameters with the assigned values in multiple places.